# How to read input via ant without it going to the nextline?

Tags: java, ant, input, build.xml

I run an interactive  program with ant. But when never the program ask for input, the cursor always goes to the next line:

```
Enter input: 
_
```

But it's supposed to be:

```
Enter input: _
```

Does anyone happen to know how to fix this?

Here's the java class

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
          System.out.print ("Enter input: ");
          //.....
   }
}
```

Here's part of the build.xml

```
<target name ="run" depends="build">
                <property name="name" value="MyClass"/>
                <java fork="yes" classname="${name}" failonerror="true">
                        <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
                </java>
</target>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of ant script?

Comment: Ok, I've just added more details.

Comment: A little bit of info about source of problem: [link](http://codefeed.com/blog/ants-io-system). Maybe it will be easier to write a console app which sometimes calls ant (if you really need such level of console control).

Comment: What happens when you run this outside ant, directly?

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.Console;
```

....

```
Console console = System.console();     
String input =
    console.readLine("Enter Input: ");
```

Console is a nice utility class in Java 6

otherwice - Scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter input: ");
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

I expect it has to do with the fork="yes".  When you fork another VM, you have two VM's writing to the same terminal.  The newline is obviously being pushed by the running Ant processor, not your custom task.

Try it without forking.  If your task is interactive, you probably don't want to fork anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you are asking for input, i.e.:

```
System.out.println("Enter input: ");
in.read(); // inputs here
```

Instead of printing a new line, just do print (without the new line character), now when you get input, it should be on the same line, i.e.:

```
System.out.print("Enter input: ");
in.read(); // inputs here
```

Comment: No, I used `System.out.print()` NOT `System.out.println()`. In fact when I run the class directly with `java MyClass`, the cursor doesn't get pushed to the next line. But when I build and run it with ant, this happens